# Javascript split function in chrome gives unexpected results

Tags: javascript

Here is the piece of code

```
str = "a,b,c";
name = str.split(",");
```

The `name` variable shows up as 'object' type in Firefox and 'string' type in chrome
Why is that happening ?
Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XujYT/17/

Also the `name` variable stores the value  `"a,b,c"` instead of the split array in chrome
http://jsfiddle.net/XujYT/23/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because `name` is a global variable used by chrome, and it’s not possible to override it without unexpected results. Try:

```
var name = str.split(","); // always use var for local variables!
```

Comment: @David Wow ! I never knew that . Any Idea what is that variable used for ?

Comment: @Sethunath: to store the window name used by `window.open` to open this window.

Comment: @Sethunath: any reason not using `var` in the first place?

Comment: @Jan-StefanJanetzky no . `var name` would do . I was just curious to know what was going on

Comment: @Sethunath the global `name` variable is not meant to be manipulated, and it doesn’t behave like regular variables. F.ex, if you assign something to it it will evaluate that value as `toString()`, so `name={}` will evaluate to `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: what i mean is: why do you define stuff in the global object anyways? you should -always- use var to get out of that horrible global objects scope.